# The concept of a specification test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, misspecification

There is a confusing facet of the concept of a specification test.

According to many textbooks, a specification test is roughly a statistical test investigating whether assumptions in a statistical model are true or not.

Here, I think, it is not clear whether specification tests are arguments for the population of interest or the data in hand.

To be specific, suppose that we imposed an assumption (or specified a model) denoted by M, and we have a data set. In this situation, a specification for M is rejected. Then, does that mean M is not appropriate to the given data? or the population?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A specification test tests whether a model is appropriate for the underlying population, not just the data. The data is a "proxy" for the population. If the dataset is too small to be a good proxy for the population, the specification tests will not reject the tested model. See e.g. the [Ramsey RESET test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey_RESET_test). There, the linear model is rejected *only if* the nonlinear terms of the nonlinear model are considered significant, which only happens if you have enough data.